# How to detect if running in the new Windows Terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, terminal, windows-terminal

An upcoming feature of the Windows Terminal preview is that it has full emoji support:

[image: Windows Powershell running in Windows Terminal]

Compared to:

[image: Windows Powershell]

In Node.js, how do I detect if I'm running in a terminal wrapped by the Windows Terminal instead of its "naked" variation? Is there an environmental variable I can extract or a synchronous test I can do?

Comment: If you're using node, what's the output of `process.env`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox https://pastebin.com/t8vn2A7z

Comment: It doesn’t look like it contains anything to uniquely identify the power shell version?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Seems like it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Apparently, checking for `WT_SESSION` is the current solution: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1040

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check for the `WT_SESSION` environmental variable which is set to a v4 UUID: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1040

If you're looking for a quick and dirty way to check, this should work:

```js
!!process.env.WT_SESSION
```

There's also a more elaborate method you can use, taking advantage of [`is-uuid`](https://github.com/afram/is-uuid), [`is-wsl`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-wsl) and `process.platform`:

```js
import isUUID from 'is-uuid';
import isWsl from 'is-wsl';

const isWindowsTerminal = (process.platform === "win32" || isWsl) && isUUID.v4(process.env.WT_SESSION);
```

Comment: Note:  `WT_SESSION` is not always set on Windows 11

Comment: Caveats:
1. If you run `cmd` inside Windows Terminal, or run a GUI program that launches another terminal emulator, this env var will be inherited.
2. If you run via ssh, WT_SESSION will not be set.
3. If you use Open Powershell Here in Windows Explorer, WT_SESSION will not be set,
because `powershell.exe` is launched outside of the Terminal app, then later attached to it.
(Source: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/11057)

Comment: Also, I would advise *against* checking that the value is a GUID. It seems this would only make it annoying to manually force detection of Windows Terminal, and make it less future proof in case they decide to change the format. I don't see any scenario where a change in the format would make it less of an indicator of running in the Windows Terminal, so better just keep it simple.

Comment: `WT_SESSION` does not appear to be set by Visual Studio 2022 when running a console app under the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach from https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6269 (in **PowerShell**):

```
function IsWindowsTerminal ($childProcess) {
    if (!$childProcess) {
        return $false
    } elseif ($childProcess.ProcessName -eq 'WindowsTerminal') {
        return $true
    } else {
        return IsWindowsTerminal -childProcess $childProcess.Parent
    }
}
```

which I then use in my profile to turn on e.g. **[oh-my-posh](https://ohmyposh.dev)**.

```
$IsWindowsTerminal = IsWindowsTerminal -childProcess (Get-Process -Id $PID)
if($IsWindowsTerminal) {
    oh-my-posh --init --shell pwsh --config $HOME\Documents\mytheme.omp.json | Invoke-Expression
}
```

Comment: If I run this under Windows Terminal, it returns `false`. `(Get-Process -Id $PID).ProcessName` is "powershell" and there is no `Parent` property for $childProcess. So it hits the else on the first run and then hits the `!$childProcess` on the second.